# Using double-quotes within double-quotes in bash

Tags: bash

```
echo "set :stage, :${brand}
set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/${brand}"
```

Im in this strange situation where I need a dynamic value and this value has to be wrapped in quotes. So for example this:

```
set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/${brand}"
```

when dynamic information will be filled it will be something like:

```
set :deploy_to, /srv/www/sony
```

but this is wrong as in the script, which I am filling, it has to be a string so the end result has to be wrapped in quotes, it has to be this:

```
set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/sony"
```

If I use these quotes ' ' the dynamic information is not filled.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the context here? You're generating a Ruby-based language from shell? A heredoc might be the more appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: ...passing your literal data into that Ruby-based language directly (as via the environment), without any code generation at all, would be even better. Think about what happens if your `$brand` contains a `#{}` string that executes random (potentially malicious) content when interpreted by Ruby as an example of the perils of code generation.

Comment: ...or if your `brand` contains a literal `"` character; ie. `brand='"; system('rm -rf /*'); #'`, this would likewise be a route to doing evil. Good practices don't let data be interpreted as code, thus averting evil.

Comment: err, `brand=$'"; system(\'rm -rf /*\'); #'`, rather (the bash `$''` syntax allows an easier way to escape single-quotes, which I'd quite completely forgotten to do it my above example, than is available in POSIX-compliant syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\"` like in

```
echo "set :stage, \"/srv/www/:${brand}\""
```

Comment: Thanks, something as simple as that has helped!

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I did some bash, but can't you just escape the quotes with a backslash?

```
set :deploy_to, "\"/srv/www/${brand}\""
```

Comment: Is this significantly different from the answer Lars gave four minutes prior?

Comment: no, but to be fair his answer wasn't here when I started composing my post... I've been ninja'd...